# Pressure Formula using calculus

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me with this question?

The pressure of an ideal gas, measured in kPa, is related to its volume, $V$, and temperature, $T$, by the equation:
$PV=0.34T$.

The temperature is measured with an error of $3$ Kelvin and the volume is measured with an error of $0.6 \ m^3$ . If it is known that the actual values are $T=282$ Kelvin and $V=3 \ m^3$, what is the maximum error in the measurement of the pressure? Round your answer to $3$ decimal places.

I know I need to solve for $P$ so $P=.34T/V$ and then I don't know what to do.  I just want to be able to understand how to do the problem before its due.

Comment: Hint : You need the derivates with respect to $V$ and $T$. Multiply them with $\Delta V$ and $\Delta T$ respectively and add the products.

Comment: I did that and I got -6.052 and thats wrong

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that you have to use the absolut value of the derivates.

Answer (score 0):

$$P=0.34\times\frac{T}{V}$$

$$P=0.34\times\frac{282\pm 3}{3\pm0.6}$$

$$\implies 0.34\times\frac{282-3}{3+.06}\leq P\leq 0.34\times\frac{282+3}{3-.06}$$

$$\implies 0.34\times{279}{3.06}\leq P\leq 0.34\times\frac{285}{2.94}$$

$$\implies 31\leq P\leq 32.959$$

The actual value of $P$ is $P=0.34\times\frac{282}{3}=31.96$

Therefore the maximum error is $32.959-31.96=0.999$

(note I chose 32.959 rather than 31 because its interval from 31.96 is the greater).